# Python reading csv file by read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

Hello data science community, how can i read a csv file without using separators? 
pd.read_csv(filename)
but without using separator
I tried but it gives me error unicode

Comment: What do you mean by "without using separators" ? Is your data separated by white spaces only ? Please edit your message by showing us a sample of what your csv file looks like.

Comment: do you mean that you don't know what the separators are in the file?

Comment: Along with the sample, please share the error trace.

Comment: Can I read a csv file without using separators the parameter sep)

Comment: If you look at [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), you'll see that `sep` defaults to comma (`,`) if not given. So you can, as long as your csv uses comma as its delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this will work:

```
import csv

with open('/Users/bandarhelal/Downloads/electronic-card-transactions-september-2019-csv-tables.csv', mode='r') as testfile:
    arr = testfile.readlines()
    for line in arr:
        print(line.replace(',', ' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import panadas as pd

data_frame = pd.read_csv(full file path)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. It is usually more helpful if you can also explain how your code solves the asker's problem. Even if it is obvious to you, doing this makes it more likely that your answer will be more helpful to future visitors.